# Eclipse development on the Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

I am moving my Eclipse development to the Mac and as far as development goes, I am completely new to the Mac. I use Eclipse to write code for Android, BlackBerry, straight Java, etc...

On the PC, I would install an instance of Eclipse into a separate folder for each platform that I was developing for.  This is so that the plugins for each of these platforms would not clash with each other.

So i would have c:\code.android\eclipse, c:\code.blackberry\eclipse, etc...

Where would I install instances of Eclipse on the Mac.  I saw a \dev folder off the root, but it didn't look like I should install there anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to create a folder Development under /Applications and put the Eclipse folder you downloaded into Development then right click on it and choose duplicate(as many times as you need it).

Finally rename the folders you duplicated "Eclipse - Java", "Eclipse - Blackberry", etc. or similar.

That's all you'll have to do.

Mac applications generally don't have an installation routine, you usually just drag and drop them to the applications folder.

Comment: that's similar to what I do. Then I cmd+i on both that folder and the actual /Developer and drag and drop the nice icon of the folder with the hammer so that it looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

you can also install separate instance just instead of c:\ put them into /Applications and named them appropriately, as simple as that...

also there is no really installation for eclipse, you just drag application into application folder and that's it.